# Adaptive card formatting in MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

How to format buttons in Adaptive card in MS Teams. Currently the card is getting rendered as 
[image]

Our aim is to render it as follows:

[image]

Any suggestion are highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello @shehanaaz, are you trying to change the button colors? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. We would like to display the buttons without fill.

Answer (score 0):

This [style feature](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.Submit.html) is introduced in adaptive card 1.2 version. But it is currently not working in MS Teams. There is an active bug already logged for this.

Comment: @shehanaazsk, do you want the adaptive button without fill ? If yes, then that is the default behavior in team. You can get it by using simple adaptive card submit action. Please let me know if you need a sample json

Comment: Yes the default option is button without fill. However they get horizontally aligned. We are looking for ways to align buttons vertically, to achieve that we have used containers. When the buttons are added within container, they get filled even without formatting.